Is Trump now a felon even if he appeals?
In Germany, an appeal (both a Berufung as well as a Revision) prevents a criminal sentence from becoming effective. The presumption of innocence (Unschuldsvermutung, also called Präsumtion der Unschuld) continues to be in force. I suppose that calling a defendant with a pending appeal a "criminal" could be considered an insult or defamation.
By contrast, the New York Times stated in a court room report: "Trump had become a felon." A quick google search shows that many other outlets share that claim.
Is Trump now a convicted felon, at least until an appeals court reverts the verdict? For example, has he lost the right to vote in Florida (or in New York, if he moved there)?

There is no assumption of innocence.  It is a presumption.

More significantly, has he immediately lost the right to associate with other convicted felons?

Yes
Common law jurisdictions allow a sort of legal time travel.
Right now, Trump is a felon. If he succeeds in his appeal he will not be a felon and he never was one. However, at the time I said he was a felon he was a felon even if it turns out he never was, so can’t be sued for defamation because what I said was true, even if it turns out later that it was false.

I see saw. See-saw ;-).

Also: Can you then cast a provisional ballot that will (only) be opened and counted when the appeal was successful?

@Peter-ReinstateMonica When I google "provisional ballot", all I find are ballots that are held up pending determining the voter's eligibility. I don't think it's something the voter can elect based on other criteria. And even if you could, it would be ineffective unless the appeal completes before the deadline to count ballots. I wouldn't expect this appeal to be even heard until after the election.

@Peter-ReinstateMonica I believe that Florida law prohibits a felon from registering to vote. If you can't register then you can't cast a provisional ballot.

@doneal24 If I am reading these 2 links correctly, Trump is allowed to vote in Florida since he is allowed to vote in NY (not be in prison for a felony conviction). Constitutional Amendment 4/Felon Voting Rights - Division of Elections - Florida Department of State and Voting After Incarceration | New York State Board of Elections
